# Keep on eye vs Keep an eye on

Tags: difference, idioms

I know the idiom "*keep **an** eye on*" and everything is clear about it.

Today I just saw this sentence:

> "*Keep **on** eye on the bathtub so that it doesn't run over*".

Is there something wrong in this sentence? or does it mean the same?
Keep on eye is another version of keep an eye on?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking about an obvious typo (*keep **on** eye on it* instead of *keep **one** eye on it* or ***...an** eye on it*).

Comment: I've downvoted and flagged this question because, just like what FumbleFingers wrote in the comment, it's simply a typo(apparently).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Keep on eye on" is not correct. It's a typo, either for "keep an eye on" or possibly "keep one eye on".